# Special preg_match for a string

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

This is my string:

```
================================================================================
                                       INPUT FILE
================================================================================
NAME = CO-c0m1.txt
|  1> ! HF def2-TZVP opt numfreq

|  2> 

|  3> % scf

|  4>      convergence tight

|  5> end

|  6> 

|  7> * xyz 0 1

|  8> C 0 0 0

|  9> O 0 0 1

| 10> *

| 11> 
| 12>                          ****END OF INPUT****
================================================================================
```

I want get this output:

```
! HF def2-TZVP opt numfreq
% scf
     convergence tight
end

* xyz 0 1
C 0 0 0
O 0 0 1
*
```

I've been trying to do for like 5 hours and can't do it, please help, this is my pregmatch:

```
$regx = '/INPUT FILE...................................................................................(.*?)........................END OF INPUT/s';
      if(preg_match($regx, $source[$i], $matches)) {
        $input[$i] = preg_replace('/\s\s\s\s+/', "\n", $matches[1]);
      }
```

I'am very new to regex and seems to be so hard.
Can someone please help me, thanks in advance :)!

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?  get all lines except blank?

Comment: just like the output, remove | n> and line breaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a regular expression that matches the lines that start with `|` followed by some spaces, then one or more digits then `>` and you need only the text that follows this prefix.

The regular expression is: `/^\|\s*\d+>(.*)$/m`. It contains a capturing group for the text you need. [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) puts the capturing fragments in `$matches[1]`:

```
preg_match_all('/^\|\s*\d+>(.*)$/m', $source[$i], $matches);
echo(implode("\n", $matches[1]));
```

You can then remove the line that contains `****END OF INPUT****` by other means ([`array_pop()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php), [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), etc.)

Check it in action: https://3v4l.org/hUEBk

The `regex` explained:

```
/             # regex delimiter
    ^         # match the beginning of the line
    \|        # match '|' (it needs to be escaped because it is a meta-character)
    \s        # match a whitespace character (space, tab)
    *         # the previous (a whitespace) can appear zero or more times
    \d        # match a digit (0..9)
    +         # the previous (a digit) can appear one or more times
    >         # match '>'
    (         # begin of a capturing group
      .*      # match any character, any number of times
    )         # end of the capturing group
    $         # match the end of the line
/             # regex delimiter
m             # multiline (regex modifier); check the regex against each line of the input string
```

Read more about [Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php).

Comment: Original txt: https://pastebin.com/BBpb1WpJ 
Idk if my code it's not working because of my original preg_match
This is my new code:
https://pastebin.com/StpanQp9 with our anwser but array is 0

Answer (score 2):

```
$p ="/[|]\s*\d*[>]\s(.+)/";
$t = "================================================================================
                                       INPUT FILE
================================================================================
NAME = CO-c0m1.txt
|  1> ! HF def2-TZVP opt numfreq

|  2> 

|  3> % scf

|  4>      convergence tight

|  5> end

|  6> 

|  7> * xyz 0 1

|  8> C 0 0 0

|  9> O 0 0 1

| 10> *

| 11> 
| 12>                          ****END OF INPUT****
================================================================================";


preg_match_all($p,$t,$res);

die(json_encode($res[1], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));

/* Output:
[
    "! HF def2-TZVP opt numfreq",
    "% scf",
    "     convergence tight",
    "end",
    "* xyz 0 1",
    "C 0 0 0",
    "O 0 0 1",
    "*",
    "                         ****END OF INPUT****"
]
 */
```

Second item of `$res` is an array that have what you want.

Comment: You could pop the last element to get the exact output the OP needs.

Comment: I guess the main issue was the regex, I fixed it, Yes he/she can remove last item easily.

Comment: True, it was more for the OP to not try to get everything using just a regex as that would make it a lot more complicated.

Comment: Thank you so much for your anwser, Idk if my code it's not working because of my original preg_match
Original txt: https://pastebin.com/BBpb1WpJ 
This is my new code: https://pastebin.com/StpanQp9
Nothing prints :(

Comment: Answered you in a new answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49274285/special-preg-match-for-a-string/49275585#49275585

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to run first regex on your text, only run this regex:

```
preg_match_all("/[|]\s*\d*[>]\s(.+)/", $source[$i], $matches);
echo(implode("\n", $matches[1]));
```

This works fine in my tests.

Comment: Thank you so much this actually worked, and I got rid off the last line too

Comment: Your welcome, But you signed as best answer the other man's answer!

Comment: It was a silly mistake and he anwsered first, but I appreciate you, taking time to anwser me.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a single regex solution to get all those data in one go:

```
^\|\h+\d+>(?!\h*\Q****END OF INPUT****\E)\h\K.+
```

Breakdown:

- `^` Match beginning of line
- `\|\h+\d+>` Match up to `digit>`
- `(?!` Start of a negative lookahead

  - `\h*` If horizental whitespace(s) exist(s)
  - `\Q****END OF INPUT****\E` And ends with *end of input*
- `)` End of lookahead
- `\h\K` Match a horizental whitespace then reset match
- `.+` Match up to the end of line

PHP code:

```
preg_match_all("~^\|\h+\d+>(?!\h*\Q****END OF INPUT****\E)\h\K.+~mi", $str, $matches);
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/9MBQU)

Output of `print_r($matches[0]);`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ! HF def2-TZVP opt numfreq
    [1] => % scf
    [2] =>      convergence tight
    [3] => end
    [4] => * xyz 0 1
    [5] => C 0 0 0
    [6] => O 0 0 1
    [7] => *
)
```

You need to do a `implode(PHP_EOL, $matches[0]);` to join values together.